# Como quebrar uma linha no título do gráfico em 2 linhas usando o ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Eu preciso quebrar alinha de título do gráfico para que ele fique na largura do próprio gráfico. O motivo é que o gráfico será usado num `grid.arrange()` e desta forma ele vai ficar estreito e o título passando da largura em que o gráfico passará a ter.

aí vai uma amostra dos dados

```
> dput(dados)
structure(list(grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("TOC", "TA"), class = "factor"), a = c(9, 5, 
2, 1, 3, 7, 16, 15, 4, 20, 6, 10, 13, 19, 18, 11, 8, 12, 17, 
14, 21, 28, 25, 33, 39, 40, 30, 29, 35, 32, 26, 23, 24, 36, 27, 
37, 34, 38, 31, 22)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

e aqui está o gráfico a partir dos dados.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(grupo, a)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.3) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = grupo), show.legend = F) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=17, size=4) +
  labs(title = "rMSSD (Root-Mean Square Sucessive NN intervals Difference)",
       x = "", y = "ms",
       tag = "A") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"))
```

> Uma pergunta adicional: Por se tratar de um nome em Inglês do acrônimo rMSSD. Como deixar somente o que está em parênteses na forma itálico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se quebrar o título com `title` e `subtitle`.
E para ter texto em itálicos, pode-se fazer com `bquote` e [`plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(grupo, a)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", size = 1, width = 0.3) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = grupo), show.legend = F) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=17, size=4) +
  labs(title = 'rMSSD',
       subtitle = bquote(italic('(Root-Mean Square Sucessive NN intervals Difference)')),
       x = "", y = "ms",
       tag = "A") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "Black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: em princípio eu até já tinha pensado nisso de colocar como subtitle. Contudo, ainda não é suficiente para ajustar à largura possível.. Diminuir o tamanho da fonte também não é legal pois eu vou fazer um grid.arrange() com 8 gráficos destes e assim ficaria muito pequeno o texto. Portanto, ainda sim, preciso tentar quebrar a linha com alguma função lim() que desconheço para esse elemento.

Comment: @gleidsonmr Tem a vantagem de ser tudo automático: o posicionamento e de ter o subtítulo com letras mais pequenas a caber numa só linha. Se não coubesse, um truque é por um newline `\n` algures. Por exemplo, a seguir ao `Root-Mean Square\n` e antes de `Sucessive`.

Comment: a dica de nova linha "\n" foi ótima. De fato, como vc mencionou, este método não automatiza outras coisas como a disposição das linhas. No fim, o Title ficou parcialmente sobrepondo o Subtitle. Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso pra ver se encontramos uma solução completa.

Comment: @gleidsonmr Basta também por um `'\n'` no título: `title = 'rMSSD\n'`.

Comment: utilizei o "\n" no subtitle = " " e depois utilizei o theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 5)) para retirar o "title" que estava ficando em cima do "subtitle". Resolveu, e ficou a contento!